# matplotlib: padding the title of subplots doesn't work in last line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have discountered a strange behaviour of the title if matplotlib subplots. I wanted to place the title of each subfigure within the subfigure. I did so using the "pad" argument in the set_title function. However, padding the titles of the last line of figures seems not to work.

A minimal example is

```
fig,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4),(ax5,ax6))=plt.subplots(3,2,sharex=True,sharey=True)
ax1.set_title("Image 1",pad=-11)
ax2.set_title("Image 2",pad=-11)
ax3.set_title("Image 3",pad=-11)
ax4.set_title("Image 4",pad=-11)
ax5.set_title("Image 5",pad=-11)
ax6.set_title("Image 6",pad=-11)
```

leading to

[image]

I tested it with 2 rows and now with 3 rows and the position of the titles last line of the last line of figures is still the default.

My question is now: Is it a bug or do I have some misunderstanding of how titles work in matplotlib subfigures?

PS: I am using Python 3.7.3 and matplotlib version 3.1

Comment: It looks very much like a bug to me. Rather than "last line", the key is that it's working for all axes that don't have xticklabels.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think you are correct. I removed the shared x-Axis, now none of the titles move doesnt move at all

Comment: Unfortunately I'm partially guilty of that bug myself; sorry for that. It broke in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13741. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16805

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It's okay. I mean there are many ways of placing text. Good to know that the bug is known...